# xor n sets of variables for use in SAT transformation

Tags: transformation, boolean-logic

I am doing a transformation from a customoized set cover problem to a sat, so I can perhaps use a sat solver for my problem.

My problem is: I have several sets of variables that interact together in a term of the sat problem; something along the lines of `x_i v x_j v x_k; y_i v y_j v y_k` .

However what I can't seem to get right is that both sets of variables must not have the same occupancy as a combination. e.g. `X_i` can be equal to `x_j`, but the whole set must not be equally occupated.

How do I express that so I can use it in a sat-solver?

Comment: i wonder if the solution was easier than i thought. can somebody correct me ? ist it possible just to go: (x_i v x_j ...) xor (y_i v y_j ...) to force the sets to have different occupancies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I succeeded with:

```
and(not((xnor x_i) and (xnor y_i))
```